# adding dll files(More than one file) as a reference in run time in WPF with example

Tags: wpf

I am having a .dll files in a folder which is inside the program folder(not in a bin).I have to add these .dll assembles as a reference at run time in a WPF application.How to add this ???...i searched many websites but I did not find for WPF ..

```
public class Loadassembly
 {
   public void assembly()
 {
System.Reflection.Assembly myDllAssembly =  Assembly.LoadFile(@"C:\Users\mouli\Desktop\Nov 11\Table_Level_Restore\Table_Level_Option\Third party dll\Microsoft.SqlServer.ConnectionInfo.dll");

Type[] types = myDllAssembly.GetTypes();
          foreach (Type typ in types)
                 {
                 object obj = Activator.CreateInstance(typ);
                 MethodBase method = System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod();
                 string methodName = method.Name;
                 string className = method.ReflectedType.Name;
                 string fullMethodName = className + "." + methodName;
                 MethodInfo mi = typ.GetMethod(fullMethodName);
                 mi.Invoke(0, null);
                }
 }
 }
```

I added this class to load assembly at run time but it is not working why???it is telling you are missing any assembly while debugging..

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple example of calling a function from DLL.

```
                    var tmp = Assembly.Load(value);
                    foreach (var cl in tmp.GetTypes())
                    {
                            foreach (var mtd in cl.GetMethods(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Static))
                            {
                                if (/* want to call */)
                                {
                                    mtd.Invoke(null, new Object[] { / params / });
                                }
                            }
                    }
```

Comment: there is no such property in that..whether your telling "Copy to output Directory" this property ..shall i set to copy always...

Comment: Dont understand where you have found "Copy to output directory".
Just go to References and view properties for a referenced dll

Comment: Hai..I am not asking for using a method in DLL....Just add .dll files as a reference at run time..

Comment: Well you can't. What are you trying to achieve?
You have two options.

Add them as reference for early binding ( and use everything from them in your app ) Or load them lately and call some functions from them. No third option, sorry.